# Show that $X_{n}\sim N(\sin(\pi n),1)$ is uniformly tight

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, random-variables

If $X_{n}\sim N(\sin(\pi n),1)$, then how do I show $X_{n} = O_{p}(1)$?

$X_{n} = O_{p}(1)$ means that for every $\epsilon$, there exists an $M$ such that $\sup_{n} P(|X_{n}|>M)<\epsilon$.

I am trying to fix an $M$ in terms of $\epsilon$, but I'm not sure what choice would make sense given the oscillating sine wave.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The $X_n$ are just standard normal distributions shifted by distance at most $1$ from zero, so you should be able to bound their tails at the same time with a suitable choice of $M$.

Concretely, show that for any $n$, $$P(|X_n| > M) = P(X_n > M) + P(X_n < M) \le P(Z+1 > M) + P(Z - 1 < M)$$
where $Z$ is standard normal.

Comment: Thanks. I see how that final expression would indicate an $M$ that works for any $\epsilon$, but how do I actually find that $M$? It seems like I need to get $Z$ values based on $\epsilon$, e.g. $Z_{\epsilon}$, then add that to 1? Or subtract it from -1?

Comment: @bobbyjohnson To be clear, for a fixed $\epsilon$ you need to find an $M_\epsilon$ that works for that $\epsilon$. The probabilities on the right-hand side can be expressed in terms of $\Phi$ (the CDF of $Z$). There won't be a closed-form expression for $M_\epsilon$ in terms of $\epsilon$, but you can state it in terms of $\Phi$.